# dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/update-manager_1%3a20.04.10.9_all.deb (--unpack)

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, google-chrome

I was running into issues with not being able to upgrade packages using `sudo apt-get upgrade`, so I was recommended to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, but it seems to be stuck on google-chrome-stable for the last hour. Is there something I can do to fix this? It also locked the frontend (as I am connecting to a remote pc using rdp), but ssh access using cmd works.

As of right now the error message looks like this:
[image]

Comment: `sudo killall update-desktop-database ` and `sudo killall dpkg`  then try `sudo apt -f install` again.  when the first command work.